# Examples of a classifying space using the bar resolution

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, visualization

While studying group (co)-homology, I've learned about how to construct a chain complex such that its cell chain complex coïnide with the bar resolution of a certain group $G$. For that we first construct the space $EG$ such that its $0$-cells are $G$, its $1$-cells are given by $G\times G$ such that each pair $(g,h)$ are glued to the $0$-skeleton by identifying its end points with the $0$-cells h and g. And in general we add $G^{n+1}$ n-cells each homeomorphic to the standard simplices $\Delta ^n$, for each $(g_0,...,g_n)=\sigma$ we have an n-cell $\Delta^{\sigma}=\Delta^n$ and we identify its faces $\delta_i\Delta^{\sigma}$ with $\Delta^{\delta_i \sigma}$.

So my problem is that I have a hard time to visualize what this first space $EG$ would look like. I've tried to compute it for a simple group like $C_2$ but without much success, maybe someone has a visual example that could help me to understand this first step of the construction ?

Comment: In general your model for $EG$ is pretty big, so it is usually not very helpful to try and visualize it. For example, if I am not mistaken $EC_2$ is (equivariantly) homeomorphic $S^\infty$ with multiplication by $-1$ (use that you have two non-degenerate simplices in each degree). Let me also point out that for any finite group there cannot be a finite dimensional model for $EG$.

Comment: This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Per site policy, comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information. Therefore I suggest that you post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

Comment: Ok so If I understood well this space is here just so we can construct BG and it's not used in practice ? @VincentBoelens